# How to ts.now().utc_strftime("%H:%M:%S.%f") in skyfield v1.26

Tags: utc, strftime, skyfield

I was tracking a satellite every second, but needed a higher sampling rate.  So I changed to every 0.25 seconds.  I want to print the utc of the sampling to a few decimal places.  I tried `ts.now().utc_strftime("%H:%M:%S.%f")` but it's printing `13:23:18.%f` instead of `13:23:18.235`.

How do I format `ts.now().utc_strftime(<format>)` to higher precision than seconds?

Comment: What version of Skyfield are you using? Including the output of `from skyfield import __version__; print(__version__)` in your question will help folks know which version of Skyfield your question is about.

Comment: update w/ version  thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Old versions of Skyfield relied internally on Python's own `time.strftime()` which, alas, lacks support for microseconds. Try upgrading to a more recent version — the current version is 1.30 — and see whether that fixes the problem?

Comment: Ouch.  Seems like an obvious feature to be there.  Thanks.

Comment: Yes, time handling on traditional Unix systems was surprisingly uninformative about fractions less than a second — the `time()` system call returned only an integer number of seconds, and older API entry points still have limits because of that convention!